# Stripe SetupIntent confirmation confusion

Tags: php, stripe-payments

I'm using Stripe and `SetupIntent` to create a `Card` to be used later on without further authentication. I am right now dealing with secure cards and testing with `4000 0000 0000 3220`.

When I create the `SetupIntent`, I go through the `next_action` process, which has the end user verify the card, and then I can save the `SetupIntent` and `Card`. Everything is fine. Note that I have the `off_session` flag set and `automatic_payment_methods`.

The issue that I have is that, even if I have delt with `next_action` at `SetupIntent`, when I'm using the `Card` to create a `PaymentIntent` to charge the customer off session, even if I set `confirm` to `false` for the  `PaymentIntent`, I'm still getting a `"status": "requires_confirmation"`

I'm trying to understand if I should be getting `requires_confirmation` if I used a confirmed `SetupIntent`. If this Card always requires a confirmation, then I cannot use it off session? Also note I'm on the server side.

```
{
  "id": "pi_3OObJKJpAkZLjTfw1Q2utR7f",
  "object": "payment_intent",
  "amount": 174,
  "amount_capturable": 0,
  "amount_details": {
    "tip": {
    }
  },
  "amount_received": 0,
  "application": null,
  "application_fee_amount": null,
  "automatic_payment_methods": null,
  "canceled_at": null,
  "cancellation_reason": null,
  "capture_method": "automatic",
  "client_secret": "pi_3O**********************_******_*********************BTuB",
  "confirmation_method": "automatic",
  "created": 1702884742,
  "currency": "cad",
  "customer": "cus_LXO9h5kOGp6GKQ",
  "description": null,
  "invoice": null,
  "last_payment_error": null,
  "latest_charge": null,
  "livemode": false,
  "metadata": {
  },
  "next_action": null,
  "on_behalf_of": null,
  "payment_method": "card_1OOLwcJpAkZLjTfwGipA1oes",
  "payment_method_configuration_details": null,
  "payment_method_options": {
    "card": {
      "installments": null,
      "mandate_options": null,
      "network": null,
      "request_three_d_secure": "automatic"
    }
  },
  "payment_method_types": [
    "card"
  ],
  "processing": null,
  "receipt_email": null,
  "review": null,
  "setup_future_usage": null,
  "shipping": null,
  "source": null,
  "statement_descriptor": null,
  "statement_descriptor_suffix": null,
  "status": "requires_confirmation",
  "transfer_data": null,
  "transfer_group": null
}
```

If I set `confirm : true` for the `PaymentIntent`, I get a `next_action`

```
object(Stripe\PaymentIntent)#40514 (40) {
  ["id"]=>
  string(27) "pi_3OOc37JpAkZLjTfw1LMEwAQm"
  ["object"]=>
  string(14) "payment_intent"
  ["amount"]=>
  int(170)
  ["amount_capturable"]=>
  int(0)
  ["amount_details"]=>
  object(Stripe\StripeObject)#40510 (1) {
    ["tip"]=>
    array(0) {
    }
  }
  ["amount_received"]=>
  int(0)
  ["application"]=>
  NULL
  ["application_fee_amount"]=>
  NULL
  ["automatic_payment_methods"]=>
  NULL
  ["canceled_at"]=>
  NULL
  ["cancellation_reason"]=>
  NULL
  ["capture_method"]=>
  string(9) "automatic"
  ["client_secret"]=>
  string(60) "pi_3OOc37JpAkZLjTfw1LMEwAQm_secret_NiTcECIwUs0UjZtoJdgkyvx8B"
  ["confirmation_method"]=>
  string(9) "automatic"
  ["created"]=>
  int(1702887581)
  ["currency"]=>
  string(3) "cad"
  ["customer"]=>
  string(18) "cus_LXO9h5kOGp6GKQ"
  ["description"]=>
  NULL
  ["invoice"]=>
  NULL
  ["last_payment_error"]=>
  NULL
  ["latest_charge"]=>
  NULL
  ["livemode"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["metadata"]=>
  object(Stripe\StripeObject)#40508 (0) {
  }
  ["next_action"]=>
  object(Stripe\StripeObject)#40505 (2) {
    ["type"]=>
    string(14) "use_stripe_sdk"
    ["use_stripe_sdk"]=>
    object(Stripe\StripeObject)#40379 (9) {
      ["directory_server_encryption"]=>
      object(Stripe\StripeObject)#40529 (4) {
        ["algorithm"]=>
        string(3) "RSA"
        ["certificate"]=>
        string(2147) "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
"
        ["directory_server_id"]=>
        string(10) "A000000003"
        ["root_certificate_authorities"]=>
        array(1) {
          [0]=>
          string(2025) "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
"
        }
      }
      ["directory_server_name"]=>
      string(4) "visa"
      ["merchant"]=>
      string(21) "acct_1BLGmTJpAkZLjTfw"
      ["one_click_authn"]=>
      NULL
      ["server_transaction_id"]=>
      string(36) "9f05b43b-b47d-4a01-ae6a-9d8350fc76a1"
      ["three_d_secure_2_source"]=>
      string(31) "payatt_3OOc37JpAkZLjTfw10V4xZcq"
      ["three_ds_method_url"]=>
      string(0) ""
      ["three_ds_optimizations"]=>
      string(2) "kf"
      ["type"]=>
      string(23) "stripe_3ds2_fingerprint"
    }
  }
  ["on_behalf_of"]=>
  NULL
  ["payment_method"]=>
  string(29) "card_1OOLwcJpAkZLjTfwGipA1oes"
  ["payment_method_configuration_details"]=>
  NULL
  ["payment_method_options"]=>
  object(Stripe\StripeObject)#40501 (1) {
    ["card"]=>
    object(Stripe\StripeObject)#40536 (4) {
      ["installments"]=>
      NULL
      ["mandate_options"]=>
      NULL
      ["network"]=>
      NULL
      ["request_three_d_secure"]=>
      string(9) "automatic"
    }
  }
  ["payment_method_types"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(4) "card"
  }
  ["processing"]=>
  NULL
  ["receipt_email"]=>
  NULL
  ["review"]=>
  NULL
  ["setup_future_usage"]=>
  NULL
  ["shipping"]=>
  NULL
  ["source"]=>
  NULL
  ["statement_descriptor"]=>
  NULL
  ["statement_descriptor_suffix"]=>
  NULL
  ["status"]=>
  string(15) "requires_action"
  ["transfer_data"]=>
  NULL
  ["transfer_group"]=>
  NULL
}
```

How do I deal with `use_stripe_sdk` in a back end environment, and why do I get a `next_action` here if I already completed it when I created the `SetupIntent` with the `Card` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're collecting payment off-session, you should pass in `off_session=true` and `confirm=true` when creating the PaymentIntent : https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_intents/create#create_payment_intent-off_session to indicate that the customer isn’t in your checkout flow during this payment attempt and can’t authenticate.